# Can a machsheva be a bracha levatala in specific circumstances?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shehakol-beracha, thought, bracha-levatala

According to [Chacham Ovadia's chiddush](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=3323&txtSearch=ovadia%20think%20swallow%20drink), if you already hold liquid in your mouth, and remembered you forgot to say Shehakol, you may "think" the bracha with the liquid in your mouth, and this bracha suffices even for drinks/food you have after this.

Question: If a person drinks liquid, and while it is in his mouth before being swallowed, he is not sure if he made a bracha, of course he should not make the bracha - at least with dibbur. But assuming that this person makes the bracha by hirhur, did he risk "saying" a bracha levatala?
In essence, can a bracha levatala ever consist of hirhur?

Comment: Your link does go to any comment from Chacham Ovadia. Could you please correct the link? In regard to whatever he says, does he happen to mention what the "liquid" is? Meaning in the context of his statement, water or all liquids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is much discussion is this in Aharonim. [R. Yitshak Yosef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhak_Yosef) writes in Yalkut Yosef (Kitsur OH 184:14, 185:4, etc.) that a mental blessing cannot be a berakha l'vatala.

[R. Zilberstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Zilberstein) quotes this in Hashukei Hemed (Pesahim 13a) from the [Sdei Hemed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Hezekiah_Medini) (Vol. I: ב: klal 115).

R. Yosef (Yalkut Yosef notes to Hilhkot Hashkamat HaBoker ch. 4) also quotes this from the [Shu"t Ginat V'radim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99) (OH I:43), but quotes some who disagree.

The [Tselah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Landau) in Berakhot (20b) considers the possibility that it could be a berakha l'vatala, but concludes that it isn't.

Comment: Thanks!! Then, if a person 1) isnt sure if he said shehakol before 2) nevertheless ingests a food/drink holding it in his mouth --> At such point of time, is he able to /should he rely on hirhur of a shehakol bracha?